# Umlaut ¨ with package tm (text mining in R)

Tags: r, special-characters, text-mining, tm

I am trying to read some PDF docs using the package `tm` for text mining in R. However, my PDF are in german and I dont know how to deal with those Special characters.

```
library(tm)
pathname <- "J:/branchwarren/docs/tm/"
raw_corpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(directory=path,encoding="UTF-8"), readerControl=list(reader=readPDF,language="de"))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(raw_corpus)
tdm_mat <- as.data.frame(tdm)
```

The Output `tdm_mat` for example is (where the columns are the frequencies in each PDF)

```
1     geschã¤ftsverlauf                             9                             9                             1                             3                             0                             0
2          gesellschaft                             1                             3                             1                             1                             1                             1
3         gesellschaft.                             0                             0                             1                             1                             1                             0
4  gesellschaftskapital                             1                             1                             1                             1                             1                             1
5            gestaltung                             1                             1                             1                             1                             1                             1
6            gesteigert                             0                             0                             2                             0                             2                             6
7              gesunden                             0                             1                             0                             1                             1                             1
8         gewinnreserve                             1                             1                             1                             1                             1                             1
9     gewinnverwendung)                             1                             1
```

As you notice, the character in the first row is not displayed correctly. It should be geschäftsverlauf.

Any help or suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: You can start the session as `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "german")` instead of using R's `utf-8` encoding method.

Comment: @Nickil Maveli, I am sorry but it does not work. Can you Detail a lil bit your Response? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but e.g. this works for me as expected:

```
library(tm)
dir.create(pathname <- tempfile())
writeLines("Der Geschäftsbericht war gut. Die Maßnahmen griffen.", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".md"))
rmarkdown::render(input=tf, output_format="pdf_document", output_file="1.pdf", output_dir=pathname)
if(all(file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext"))))) { # see ?readPDF
  raw_corpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(directory=pathname, encoding="UTF-8"), readerControl=list(reader=readPDF,language="de"))
  tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(raw_corpus)
  tdm_mat <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(tdm)) 
  tdm_mat
}
#                  1.pdf
# der                  1
# die                  1
# geschäftsbericht     1
# griffen.             1
# gut.                 1
# maßnahmen            1
# war                  1
```

My `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    
...
tm_0.6-2            NLP_0.1-8   
...
```

Maybe an encoding mismatch? Try providing input data + your sessionInfo to debug & reproduce the error.